# Android Webview and Flash + plupload

Tags: android, flash, plugins, webview

I need to get http://www.plupload.com/ working in my webview
I did try

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

and nothing happens.. 
I did install : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rg2333g53t244frf.flash.player
and its working.. but the filechooser is not nice (like default browser) and i cant ask clients to install this package and check unknown sources..

Someone here with a valid solution ? (Could i half silently install the above apk from my assets folder without root ?)
Why is flash working in normal android Browser and in my webview only if i install the above Plugin ?

Comment: Try adding `.setPluginsEnabled(true)` and `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to your `<application>` tag in the manifest.

Comment: @Raghav I had that hardwareAccelerated..true                              And ? I guess .setPluginsEnabled is deprecated...    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); or   mWebView.setPluginsEnabled(true); isnt valid or even .. did see mWebView.setPluginState(PluginState.ON); on stackoverflow but even not valid

Comment: Nice .. setPluginState This method was deprecated in API level 18. Plugins will not be supported in future, and should not be used. So Google did destroy flash support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer : So there is no solution to this Problem ! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html

Google did cancel any Plugin support in API level 18. This method was deprecated in API level 18. This method supports the obsolete plugin mechanism, and will not be invoked in future .

**Note :**
Today I did write a solution thats similar to plupload.. it would open local filechooser and resize and change quality prior to upload.

[Android CustomWebChromeClient openFileChooser Resize Image before Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667881/android-customwebchromeclient-openfilechooser-resize-image-before-upload/18707044#18707044)