# How to upload multiple files by webview?

Tags: java, android, webview

I have created one project with Webview to call my Website in the mobile app.
(done in Android App/Java).
I can upload multiple files when I work in Website but I cannot select multiple files, but the only single file.
I have tried many of the codings given in stackoverflow, but I couldn't get a solution for my issue.
Kindly help me to activate this feature. And I'm new to app creation, kindly guide me where to add and what to add.
below I have given the coding

i tried optnfiechooser option, 
intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true) and other codes too.

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Uri[] results = null;
        //Check if response is positive
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUMA) {
                    return;
                }
                if (intent == null) {
                    //Capture Photo if no image available
                    if (mCM != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUMA = null;
    } else {
        if (requestCode == FCR) {
            if (null == mUM) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUM = null;
        }
    }
}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException
{
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
}


public void onClick_GoBack(View v)
{
    if (wv.canGoBack())
        wv.goBack();
}


public void onClick_Home(View v)
{
    wv.loadUrl(MY_SITE_HOME);
}


public void onClick_Info(View v)
{
    wv.loadUrl(MY_SITE_INFO);
}
```

**Inner Classes**

```
class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient
{
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress)
    {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

        loadingProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);

        txtState.setText(Integer.toString(newProgress) + "%");
        if (newProgress >= 100)
        {
            loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txtState.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if (newProgress <= 10)
        {
            loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtState.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    @Override


    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)

    {

        if (mUMA != null)
        {
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mUMA = filePathCallback;
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null)
        {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }

        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }


    }


}





class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view,String url,Bitmap favicon)
    {
        super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String Url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(Url);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view,String url)
    {
        super.onPageFinished(view,url);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Choose Files");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            return true;

Comment: //permission in android manifest::        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Choose Files");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            return true;

Comment: please don't post code in comments. use the [edit] link if you need to add / change something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upload multiple images in my WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251993/how-do-i-upload-multiple-images-in-my-webview)